# Having first of unnamed arguments optional

Tags: python, r, function, parameters, arguments

Is there a way to make the first argument of a function optional?

```
myFunction <- function(a = NULL, b, c) {
  if(!is.null(a)) {
    d <- a + c
  } else {
    d <- b +c
  }
  return(d)
}

myFunction(1, 2)  # Fails, because c is missing
```

In a way, this is obvious, because the unnamed arguments are matched in the order they are given.

But on the other hand, *R* could also try to look at the number of arguments given and deduce that it must be the optional argument which is missing.

My example is in *R*, but the same principle is as far as I know true in *Python*.

Comment: what's wrong with `function(b, c, a = NULL)`? How should R/Python know if the values you pass into your function are a and b or a and c or b and c? This can't work. In python you have the option to pass *args, but I think that would overdo it for your simple example.

Comment: You could check for c being missing and compute on that basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `python` you can use an asterisk `*` to have a default argument in the first position. **BUT this is only a side-effect** of the asterisk. In fact, the asterisk causes all arguments AFTER the asterisk to be *named* arguments.  Thus you must pass them to the function as named arguments, for example with `b=1, c=2`. Try it out:

```
def myFunction(*, a=None, b, c):
    if a is not None:
        d = a + c
    else:
        d = b +c
    return d

myFunction(b=1, c=2)
```

Unluckily I can only speak for python. But as far as I know using named arguments will also work for `R`.

Comment: That's nice, I didn't know about that feature in Python! But still I am confused how this is better than just rotating the arguments of the function. I hope this will be clarified soon

Comment: Like this you can pass all arguments to a function unordered. This has several benefits: Changes to the order of the arguments in the function definition do not cause strange errors on the user-side. This is especially helpful if the user is not the programmer and thus has no idea what is happening on the backend of the code. Furthermore you can easily unzip arguments stored in a `dict` like `dict_of_args` (or stored in several dicts) into *any* function with `my_func(a=5, **dict_of_args, b=23.9)`. dict arguments can also be mixed freely with standard keyword arguments like `a=5` or `b=23.9`.

Comment: In my experience especially the case of changing functions arguments in the definition happens really often during the beta-phase of a code, causing lots of confusion. Even if the user is also the beta-tester and the programmer. ;) Often it is just extremely complicated to keep track of all function definitions you have with thousands/tenthousands LOC.

Answer (score 0):

In R, named arguments would work.

in python, to avoid such ambiguities, declaring such a function would give a very self-explainable syntax error.

```
SyntaxError: non-default argument follows default argument
```

a way to bypass this would be to add an asterisk after the default argument(s), to suggest that all next arguments will be given by name.

e.g.

```
def myFunction(a=None, *, b, c):
    pass
```

but then you can only call the function with 0 to 1 positional arguments and exactly 2 named arguments